# Rails 5 CarrierWave Polymorphic Image upload in Nested Form throws NoMethod Error "undefined method `image_changed?'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, nested-forms, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic image I am trying to get to upload via CarrierWave, but I can't seem to get all the details right. Currently, I am getting the NoMethod error in the title, "undefined method `image_changed?'" I see there are many related questions already posted, but the solutions provided haven't been applicable to my case, at least that I've been able to find. Any help is appreciated. Here is the relevant code. Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Uploader:

```
# app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb
`class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [280, 280]
  end

  version :small_thumb, :from_version => :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [20, 20]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Image Model:

```
#app/models/image.rb
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Post Model:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  has_one :image, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150, minumum: 3 }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }

  scope :featured, -> { where(is_featured: true) }
  scope :authored_by, -> (user) { where(:user => user) }
end
```

Post Controller:

```
#app/controllers/admin/posts_controller
class Admin::PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def update
    unless params[:post][:image].empty?
      @post.build_image(params[:post][:image][:original_filename]).save
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to permalink_path(:blog => @blog.name.parameterize, :date => @post.link_date, :title => @post.title.parameterize) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :user_id, :weblog_id, :is_featured, :category_ids => [], :tag_ids => [],
        image_attributes: [:image])
    end
end
```

Edit Form:

```
#app/views/admin/posts/_form.html.erb
<div class="container">
<%= form_for [:admin,post], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :title %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :content %><br/>
      <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control ckeditor" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.check_box :is_featured %>
      <%= f.label :is_featured %>?
    </div>

    <h4>Image</h4>
    <%= f.fields_for Image.new do |i| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= image_tag(post.image_url, class: "img-responsive")  if post.image? %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= i.label :image, "Choose Image" %><br/>
            <%= i.file_field :image %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-group margin-top30">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: see https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1058

Comment: That seemed to be a problem with migrations. My migrations are up to date.

Comment: I'm moving on to Refile. After three days of this I need to find a solution.